# d3js chart update triggered on websocket message

Tags: javascript, d3.js, websocket, autobahn

Running an autobahn websocket server in Python and picking up json updates in the html frontend. The value (in this case "temp") is being displayed as a number with innerHTML when message arrive and that part works fine.

We also got a dial chart (d3js) but the update is initiated by the setInterval function at the end of the code which is far from ideal. How can I make the gauge update 'onmessage' through the websocket?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//---the websocket part--
var sock = null;
var displaynumber = null;
var tempdata = null;

window.onload = function () {
  var wsuri;
  displaynumber = document.getElementById('disp');

  if (window.location.protocol === "file:") {
    wsuri = "ws://...:9000";
  } else {
    wsuri = "ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":9000";
  }

  //set up a new websocket
  if ("WebSocket" in window) {
      sock = new WebSocket(wsuri);
  } else if ("MozWebSocket" in window) {
      sock = new MozWebSocket(wsuri);
  } else {
      disp("Browser does not support WebSocket!");
               window.location = "http://autobahn.ws/unsupportedbrowser";
  }

  if (sock) {
    //sock.onopen = function() {};

    sock.onclose = function(e) {
      sock = null;
    };

    sock.onmessage = function(e) {
      // e.data will be sent as a string and need to be converted to object
      var jsondata = JSON.parse(e.data);
      tempdata = jsondata.temp;
      disp(tempdata + " C");
    };
  }

  function disp(m) {
    displaynumber.innerHTML = m;
  }


  //----This is the dial chart part

  dialChart();

  function dialChart() {
    var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
      size: 300,
      clipWidth: 300,
      clipHeight: 300,
      ringWidth: 60,
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 100,
      transitionMs: 1000,
    });

    powerGauge.render();

    function updateReadings() {
      powerGauge.update(tempdata);
    }

    updateReadings();
    setInterval(function() {
      updateReadings();
    }, 2 * 1000);
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the definition of `dialChart`, add `return powerGauge`. Then when you call `dialChart();`, save the result to a variable. Then, instead of writing to `tempdata` in the socket callback, call `powerGaugeVariable.update(jsondata.temp)`.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!